# PineScript | Labels | Placement Issue

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have an issue placing my label. I use the input.time so that the user can place the starting point. I want the script generate a label above/below of the bar according to input.time value.

Issue: I want the label to be placed above (In a short trade) / below (In a Long Trade) the bar.

[image]

Script:

```
// Input I used | Time
barTime  = input.time(title="Bar Time", defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2022 13:30 +0000"), 
confirm=true)

// Label
SL_label = label.new(
 x = barTime,
 y = close,
 text= trailType == "Long" ? "Long T" : "Short T",
 color = trailType == "Long" ? color.green : color.red,
 style = trailType == "Long" ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down,
 textcolor = color.white,
 xloc = xloc.bar_time)
```

I think the issue is that the y is set equal to closing price and thats why the label is updating with each bar. The issue is I dont know how to make a variable that would interpret the closing price of a bar while using input.time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
// Input I used | Time
barTime  = input.time(title="Bar Time", defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2022 13:30 +0000"), 
confirm=true)

// Label
SL_label = label.new(
 x = bar_index,
 y = na,
 yloc= trailType == "Long" ? yloc.belowbar : yloc.abovebar,
 text= trailType == "Long" ? "Long T" : "Short T",
 color = trailType == "Long" ? color.green : color.red,
 style = trailType == "Long" ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down,
 textcolor = color.white)
```

Comment: "y = na" completely removes the label.